# Screen Orientation Xcode 4.3 iOS5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation

I am trying to have this view rotate, so that when a youtube video is played, it can be viewed full screen.

The view is embedded inside both a navigation view controller, and a tabBar view controller.

Using Xcode 4.3 target deployment is iOS 5.1, testing on both a tethered iPhone 4, and the simulator on iPhone.

I have added:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

To my view controller, which should allow the screen to rotate based on the device orientation.

Also note: I have landscape enabled in my info settings, and verified in my plist. 
This is my first time posting to stackoverflow. I hope the above is clear.

Here is the full .m for reference:

```
//  Created by Jacob Topping on 12-03-20.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 The Melon Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "WebOneViewController.h"

@interface WebOneViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebOneViewController
@synthesize webOne;
@synthesize rotateWeb;
@synthesize follow;
@synthesize earnestWeb;
@synthesize ronWeb;
@synthesize richardWeb;
@synthesize davidWeb;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSString *david = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/YSbQ1SDwtgM";
    NSURL *url7 = [NSURL URLWithString:david];
    NSURLRequest *davidUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url7];
    [davidWeb loadRequest:davidUrl];

    NSString *richard = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/6jL_1kJ6pno";
    NSURL *url6 = [NSURL URLWithString:richard];
    NSURLRequest *richardUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url6];
    [richardWeb loadRequest:richardUrl];

    NSString *ron = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/E0EmDSg3YXY";
    NSURL *url5 = [NSURL URLWithString:ron];
    NSURLRequest *ronUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url5];
    [ronWeb loadRequest:ronUrl];

    NSString *earnest = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/oTG7JtdSpT8";
    NSURL *url4 = [NSURL URLWithString:earnest];
    NSURLRequest *earnestUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url4];
    [earnestWeb loadRequest:earnestUrl];

    NSString *website3 = @"http://twitter.com/search/?src=hash&q=%23creb13";
    NSURL *url3 = [NSURL URLWithString:website3];
    NSURLRequest *requestUrl3 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url3];
    [follow loadRequest:requestUrl3];

    NSString *website2 = @"http://themeloninc.com/The_Melon_Inc./app/Slider/demo/rotate.php";
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:website2];
    NSURLRequest *requestUrl2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
    [rotateWeb loadRequest:requestUrl2];

    NSString *website = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/J2EWRG-epes";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:website];
    NSURLRequest *requestUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webOne loadRequest:requestUrl];

    //<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/J2EWRG-epes" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1150)];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setRichardWeb:nil];
    [self setRonWeb:nil];
    [self setEarnestWeb:nil];
    [self setFollow:nil];
    [self setRotateWeb:nil];
    [self setWebOne:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

@end
```